# Using summary formats entered in Xcode at the lldb command line

Tags: xcode, lldb

I entered a format in using the "Edit Summary Formats..." dialog. If I then type commands to the (lldb) debugging prompt in the Xcode debug area it does not know about that format.

I could not find a way to list all the ones I typed into the dialog so that I could paste them into a .lldbinit file.

I am using Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

The Xcode "Edit Summary Format" feature does not in fact use the lldb built-in summary formats (what you get to with "type summary add".)  The Xcode summaries predated lldb, and the syntax for the formats is different, so the two features are currently independent of one another.

OTOH, Xcode will obey the type summaries you enter in the lldb command line, so you still can use lldb formats in your .lldbinit.  That's just not what you enter in the Xcode Summary Formats dialog.